# Groovy static analysis for finding variable modifications

Tags: groovy, static-analysis

I have a simple task which requires finding the modification of variables in a given code. This will be a static analysis. For instance, given a variable (e.g., age), I would like to create a list or tree (a data structure) that gives me what modifies this variable and preferably the function name that makes the modification (as a return) or any other auxiliary information. I start writing my script, yet I see that it's very error-prone as I need to consider many cases such as nested loops, etc.

Would you suggest me where to start?

Comment: You're trying to do this without a real parser?  Why?

Comment: The code uses APIs and compiles at cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code to be analyzed happens to be `Groovy` code then you could write an AST transformation (probably a global one) that walks the code and obtains the information you seek.

The Groovy documentation site has a section on AST Transformations, have a look at http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_compile_time_metaprogramming
This page describes existing AST xforms and how you can develop your own. I'd recommend browsing the code that implements the standard AST xforms such as `@Immutable`, `@Cannonical`, and others.

CodeNarc (http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/) is a static code analyzer for Groovy code, inspired by PMD. It also relies on AST xforms.
GContracts (https://github.com/andresteingress/gcontracts) is another tool implemented using AST xforms. These two can serve as a basis for understanding more about AST transformations.

OTOH if the analyzed code happens to be Java then AST transformations will not help you.